# How to perform a redirect to custom page after node save or delete?

Tags: 8, redirection

What I'm trying to do doesn't work, I still get redirected to /node/{id}:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'callback_set_redirect';
}
function callback_set_redirect($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('custom.landing.page');
}
```

Comment: This is what I found in _/core/modules/node/src/NodeForm.php_ 
`If saving is an option, privileged users get dedicated form submit
     buttons to adjust the publishing status while saving in one go.
     @todo This adjustment makes it close to impossible for contributed
       modules to integrate with "the Save operation" of this form. Modules
       need a way to plug themselves into 1) the ::submit() step, and
       2) the ::save() step, both decoupled from the pressed form button.`

Comment: You can use [https://www.drupal.org/project/rules](Rules) module.

Comment: Are you sure that your custom submit function is even called?

Comment: It could also be that another submit function overrides your custom redirect later.

Answer (score 10):

Basically the code will work for submit action alone, but drupal node save form have many actions, I think you would have logged in as admin and trying it, then follow the code below.

if you want this to be work for other actions too, That means login as admin and see the node save button, you will have select option "save and publish" , "save and unpublish". as mentioned

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

//hook_form_alter
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
    if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
      $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'callback_submit';
    }
  }
}


function callback_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('custom.page');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using hook_form_alter, you'll need to do two things

1) make sure that it's a node form
2) add a custom submit handler to each submit button.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if (isset($form['#entity_type']) && $form['#entity_type'] == 'node') {
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
        $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_form_submit';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then for the submit function, you can use whatever logic you want. You can compare with NodeForm::save, where it sends you either to the canonical node page or to the front page based on the current user's access permissions.

If you wanted to change this behavior so that it stays on the current node form, you could do this:

```
function mymodule_node_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  if ($node->id()) {
    if ($node->access('edit')) {
      $form_state->setRedirect(
        'entity.node.edit_form',
        ['node' => $node->id()]
      );
    }
    else {
      $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use your custom landing page, you just replace the redirect with the code you're already using:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('custom.landing.page');
```

Note that this won't override when there is a "destination" $_GET parameter, such as at the /admin/content page.

To remove the destination parameter from the /admin/content page, you'll want to uncheck "destination" checkbox under "Content: Operations links (Operations)" in that views fields.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had success using Symfony RedirectResponse:

```
function callback_set_redirect($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $url = Url::fromRoute("custom.landing.page")->toString();
  $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
  $response->send();
}
```

Comment: You should not use a response, since it doesn't allow hover modules to change the redirect, if necessary.

Comment: Worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong with the original code so something else is probably amiss.  It works fine for me.

However, `custom.landing.page` must be a defined route and parameters (if there are any) need to be passed in like so:

```
  $form_state->setRedirect("custom.landing.page", [
    'parameter1' => 42,
  ]);
```

See [FormState::setRedirect()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.2.x) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the [Node Save Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect) module for this functionality. It adds an option to a content type that says "what to do after saving new content".

> **What is this?**
>
> This module provides a method of specifying a location to take the user after saving a piece of content.

Comment: This module wasn't fully ported to Drupal 8 yet.