# How can I insert fields from custom content to custom form?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a problem with form. I had to create a custom content with fields. User can put variables into those fields and save to database, for example "Anna" into column `field_student_name` in table `node__field_student_name`. I see this connection where every field from this content type is saved under particular node.

Now I need to create a form with fields, which values will go to the same database tables, for example in this form I have a form field where I put "Tom", and this value is saved in table `node__field_student_name` in column `field_student_name` (the same as Anna in custom content).

At this moment I see two main potential ways to accomplish this task:

1. insert form from custom content to my new form  with entity.form_builder

I added this two lines info code:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(['type' => 'my_students']);
$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);
return $form
```

And this works fine, but I need only part of those fields :( And I don't wanna see section for admin like "add new revision" etc. Moreover, "Submit" button is on the top of the page

2. Create a form and in submit function do something like

   $node->set('title', 'titile1')

but I prefer way #1. Besides that, I don't know how to do it with way #2. I don't know how can i put variables from $form['student]' into `field_student_name` column in `node__field_student_name` table. Moreover i am not sure if it is ok and if nodes id etc will be added in correct way.

To sum up, I think way #1 is better and easier but I don't have such a big knowledge to do this  and maybe here are more advanced, helpful people who can help me.

EDIT

I've create new mode student_user in student content type:

**core.entity_view_mode.node.student_user.yml**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - node
id: node.student_user
label: student
targetEntityType: node
cache: true
```

**core.entity_view_display.node.student.student_user.yml**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - core.entity_view_mode.node.student_user
    - field.field.node.student.field_name
    - node.type.student
  module:
    - options
    - user
id: node.student.student_user
targetEntityType: node
bundle: student
mode: student_user
content:
  field_name:
    weight: 103
    label: above
    settings:
      thousand_separator: ''
      prefix_suffix: true
    third_party_settings: {  }
    type: list_default
    region: content
hidden:
  links: true
```

and here i tried with **routing**

student.student_user:
path: '/test'
defaults:
_entity_view: 'node.student_user'
_title: 'Students'
requirements:
_permission: 'access content'
_entity_access: 'node.view'

I received an error

```
RuntimeException: Failed to find entity of type node in route named student.student_user
```

And then i tried with form

i added **core.entity_form_display.node.student.student_form.yml** and **core.entity_form_mode.node.student_form.yml**

and then i tried return it in **controller**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\student\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Routing;

class TestController extends ControllerBase {


  function test() { 

    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(['type' => 'student']);
    
    $form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node, 'student_form');
   
    return $form;
  }
}
?>
```

error

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException: The "node" entity type did not specify a "student_form" form class.
```

Comment: Do you know that any entity can have multiple "form modes"? Just like in frontend, a node can have a "teaser" and a "full" view mode, in backend a node can have a default "edit" form mode showing all input fields and a custom "only_firstname" form mode with only one input field.

Comment: See modules https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control or https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_manager

Answer (score 0):

An entity can have multiple form modes, so you can exclude some fields in different form modes and leave fields that you want to display.

So, you can create form mode "custom_form_mode", go to manage fields, choose "custom_form_mode" and arrange fields.

In the custom code, you can use the code that you mention in #1, but with an extra argument in the `getForm` method, which is `$operation`, and that one is the form mode that you want to use to display form.

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(['type' => 'my_students']);
$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node, 'custom_form_mode');
return $form
```

Comment: Very thanks for response. Actually I am working on it right now and I see and error. I will update my question and insert my code

Comment: It was my bad, sorry. Operation is the operation, like Edit, Delete, Register, etc.  That's not the argument related to form mode. Instead, can you please try to use the approach as it's described here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_get_form_display/8.9.x?

Comment: actually it works, i have several forms on my page, but right now i try to disable redirection because when i click submit related to one form, it's redirecting me to summary page. And i've spend few hours on that so far, so maybe this approach is not good though

Comment: i followed https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163626/how-to-perform-a-redirect-to-custom-page-after-node-save-or-delete and stopped form redirect :)