# Multiple forms on one page

Tags: 8, forms

I try to input several forms into one page via Controller. With code which is
under, I see those forms but after submit one of them, nothing happens. Any of data is send to database. Has anyone idea how to fix this?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;
namespace Drupal\student\Controller;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity;
use Drupal\node\NodeForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Routing;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;

class SFormController extends ControllerBase {

  function new_form() { 
    
    $build = [];
  
    foreach ($stud as $id => $name) {
      
      $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(['type' => 'student']);
      $form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node, 'student_form');
      
      $build[] = $form;
    }   
    return $build;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean multiple versions of the same form on a single page?

Comment: yes, exactly. After page inspect i see they have different id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the form ID dynamic, so that it is different for each instance on the page. As you're extending EntityForm, you'll have to extend it, then register your form on the node class, and finally call your form class.

1. Extend the entity form:

   ```
   class MyEntityForm extends EntityForm {
     public function getFormId() {
       // The dynamic form ID allows for the form to be
       // reused on a page.
       return parent::getFormId() . '-' . $this->getEntity()->id();
     }
   }
   ```

2. Register your form class on the node entity type:

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
    */
   function HOOK_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
     $node = &$entity_types['node'];
     $node->setFormClass('my_form_type', 'Drupal\[MODULE]\Form\MyEntityForm');
   }
   ```
3. Call your form from your controller:

   ```
     $form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node, 'my_form_type');
   ```

Comment: And can i add this to Controller? Or should I change controller to form and create function build() instead of custom newForm() like above?

Comment: You add this to your custom form. It's not related to the controller.

Comment: Looking at your code, I can see you are passing an unsaved node to the form. This means that the entity ID will return null, and the code above as it stands will not work as all instance of the form will still have the same form ID. You will need to decide how the forms can be uniquely identified on your site, and return a dynamic form ID accordingly.

Comment: Are You able to show the most correct way? And I am not sure if i understood you correctly with "You add this to your custom form. It's not related to the controller". Should I change everything to be a Form, and not controller?

Comment: Ahh, I see, it's not a form you've created. I've updated my response accordingly.

Comment: The problem is, that i have those fields from custom content and I've created new form display. I didn't implement those fields in any Form.php. And how can i get $node in my controller?

Comment: And it don't have to be a controller. I can move everything to Form.php, I just thought it is a good way to do this too

Comment: See my updated response above.

Comment: Where should i put  code from step 1 and 2? Should i put $node to controller arguments? I tried put it to .module but i see an error `Class 'EntityForm' not found`

Comment: You need to extend `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm` with a `use` function in your code. As for where to put the code, that's getting into PHP OOP discussions, which are more than I can put in the comments. The solution above requires an understanding of PHP OOP, class extensibility, and autoloading with namespaces.

Comment: `function student_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node']->setFormClass('student_form', 'Drupal\node\NodeForm');
}` As you can see here i impelent NodeForm class. How can i connect this with your class? (step 1)

Comment: I am closer but I need to disable redirect, i guess

Comment: i've added `public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {    
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl('<current>');
    return;` to `class MyEntityForm extends EntityForm` with no luck :( any ideas?

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163626/how-to-perform-a-redirect-to-custom-page-after-node-save-or-delete that is the answer, now is ok

Comment: Please mark this question as the answer if it was correct.